# getDOMNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, frontend

I am creating a modal using ReactJS and Bootstrap.js. 
my App.js is:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  showModal: function() {
    $(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
  },
  render : function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Show Modal
        </button>
        <Modal ref="modal" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

when I clicked on **show modal** console give me error of getDOMNode is not a function.

**PS:** Please Don't suggest using React-Bootstrap I wan't to create this by using normal bootstrap.js.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`getDOMNode` is deprecated and has been replaced with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode).

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, I am using React 0.14.* and getDOMNode should work with a warning but It's not working.

Comment: Try `console.log(this.refs)` and see if you've got anything sensible in there. Good way to debug.

Comment: yes @AkshatMahajan I am getting **Object {modal: Constructor}** in console which has _ props, context, refs, state, updater _ as a key.

Comment: And can you see a `modal` key in there?

Comment: yes... and modal has constructor as **Constructor {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: null…}**

Comment: Not this is the cause of your issue, but I think you should use `this.refs.modal.getDOMNode().modal()`, without the jQuery selector.

Comment: `<Modal>` is a React component, thus it does not have DOM Node bound to it.

Comment: @Kujira that is incorrect. In the code above there would be a corresponding DOM node to `<Modal>`.

Comment: [When attaching a ref to a DOM component like <div />, you get the DOM node back; when attaching a ref to a composite component like <TextInput />, you'll get the React class instance. In the latter case, you can call methods on that component if any are exposed in its class definition.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

Isn't `<Modal>` a latter case?

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem is somewhere else than react. You can find a [working codepen of your code here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/eZxPrE?editors=0010). Where I replaced modal component with input, and `modal()` function with `focus()`. The `getDOMNode()` works there fine. What is your exact react version (14.what) ?

Comment: If the `<Modal>` is a stateless function, `refs` won't work. That may be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

change your line

```
$(this.refs.modal.getDOMNode()).modal();
```

to

```
$(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.modal)).modal();
```